# Edit content of a custom block SonataPageBundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sonata-admin

I have installed and configured SonataPageBundle as explained in the documentation. i'm trying to figure out how to render in SonataAdmin the content of my custom block. I declared my block in config.yml, i created a service,controller, routing and the page that i want to edit the block of content. I have already run the following command:

```
php app/console sonata:page:update-core-routes --site=all
php app/console sonata:page:create-snapshots --site=all
```

Unfortunately the content inside of my block is not render in the backend. i have two pictures that show you my problem:

My backend:

[image: picture1]

This is how i would like it to be of course with my content in my block.
Sonata Sandbox:

[image: picture2]

This is what i did so far:

Routing:

```
block:
    path: index/block
    defaults:  {  _controller: FLYBookingsBundle:Default:myblock }
```

DefaultController:

```
public function myblockAction()
    {
        return $this->render('FLYBookingsBundle:Default:myblock.html.twig');
    }
```

Service.yml

```
sonata.block.service.myblock:
  class: FLY\BookingsBundle\Block\MyBlockService
  arguments: [ "sonata.block.service.myblock", @templating, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
  tags:
    - { name: sonata.block }
```

MyBlockService

```
<?php
namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Block;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Model\BlockInterface;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BaseBlockService;
use Sonata\BlockBundle\Block\BlockContextInterface;
class MyBlockService extends BaseBlockService
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($type, $templating, $em)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'MyBlock';
    }

    public function getDefaultSettings()
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function validateBlock(ErrorElement $errorElement, BlockInterface $block)
    {
    }

    public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper, BlockInterface $block)
    {
    }

    public function execute(BlockContextInterface $blockContext, Response $response = null)
    {
        $settings = array_merge($this->getDefaultSettings(), $blockContext->getBlock()->getSettings());

        $data = count($this->em->getRepository("ApplicationSonataPageBundle:Page")->findAll());

        return $this->renderResponse('FLYBookingsBundle:Default:myblock.html.twig', array(
            'block' => $blockContext->getBlock(),
            'settings' => $settings,
            'data' => $data,
        ), $response);
    }
}
```

myblock.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SonataPageBundle:Block:block_base.html.twig' %}
{% block block %}
    <p> test test test </p>
{% endblock %}
```

.

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [sonata_page_bundle]
    context_manager: sonata.page.block.context_manager
    blocks:
        sonata.user.block.menu:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.block.service.myblock: ~
        sonata.block.service.container:
        sonata.page.block.container:

etc....
```

Comment: So, what's the problem exactly? Please make sure your question is verifiable [as mentioned in this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others easily can help you.

Comment: @Demitrian I want to be able to edit from the backend the content inside of `{% extends 'SonataPageBundle:Block:block_base.html.twig' %}
{% block block %}
    <p> test test test </p>
{% endblock %}` if i click on Shared Blocks ->Add new -> i can see there is my new Block with the name <<MyBlock>>. i did update my routes and snapshots, when i click on Pages i can see my new page in the list <<  block /index/block>> but i can't see the content inside of the block that i want to dit.  I hope with this explanation you can understand my problem.

Comment: Look at the sonata sandbox picture you can see that when a user is on the page {compose} there is a block content and he can add or edit the text inside of the block content [picture1](http://www.noelshack.com/2016-08-1456300771-sand1.jpg) . But look at my picture you can see that there is not even the textarea content to add some content.[picture2](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/08/1456300881-sand2.jpg).

Comment: Please add the information to your question so that others easily understand the problem when they read it.

Comment: @Demitrian I added some informations in my post.

Comment: I'm still stuck with this problem , i really need help. Thank you